# How to indent back to previous level in Emacs (text-mode)?

Tags: emacs, indentation

When using Emacs's text mode, I find it handy to use the default indentation method with below features:

1. When I am at some indentation level, hitting <kbd>C-j</kbd>
   will automatically bring me to the next line with identical
   indentation level
2. When I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the indentation will further right by some amount (usually to align with the next word in previous line)

However, I find it difficult to go back by one indentation level. E.g. If the current cursor is at the position of `|` as below:

```
Line 0: some text here
        Line 1: some text here
                Line 2: some text here
               |Line 3: some text here
```

what can I do to bring the cursor to align with "L" in line 1?
Note the amount of spaces of each level indentation is not fixed, as it is usually align to the 2nd  word of previous line. So it seems not proper to use reducing 4-spaces as indent to previous level.

Just curious whether there is any predefined / customized function for such purpose. It seems natural to seek for a corresponding "left-indent" command if the text-editor already provides a "right-indent" one.

Comment: Please move this question to emacs.stackexchange.com